# How to get a date from year, month, week of month and Day of week in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, which looks like below

[image]

I want to create a new column, which tells the exact date from the information from all the above columns. The code should look something like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month']+df['WeekOfMonth']+df['DayOfWeek']+df['Year'])
```

Comment: Is there error in the sample data ?  The 3rd row, 2018 Oct 5th week, there is no Friday.  Only till Wednesday in that week in the month.   Let me know whether your data could have such invalid figures and how you would like to handle it.  Set at month-end or wrap around to the next month ?

Comment: Feel free to let me know if any clarification required on my solution or you have any further requirement. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround for your case. You will need to define the dictionaries for the months and the days of the week.

```python
month = {"Jan":"01", "Feb":"02", "March":"03", "Apr": "04", "May":"05", "Jun":"06", "Jul":"07", "Aug":"08", "Sep":"09", "Oct":"10", "Nov":"11", "Dec":"12"}

week = {"Monday":1,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":4,"Friday":5,"Saturday":6,"Sunday":7}
```

With this dictionaries the transformation that I used with a custom dataframe was:

```python
rows = [["Dec",5,"Wednesday", "1995"],
            ["Jan",3,"Wednesday","2013"]]
            
            
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Month","Week","Weekday","Year"])

df['Date'] = (df["Year"] + "-" + df["Month"].map(month) + "-" + (df["Week"].apply(lambda x: (x - 1)*7) + df["Weekday"].map(week).apply(int) ).apply(str)).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

However you have to be careful. With some data that you posted as example there were some dates that exceeds the date range. For example, for

```
row = ["Oct",5,"Friday","2018"]
```

The date displayed is 2018-10-33. I recommend using some logic to filter your data in order to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: @Abhaykumar. If it is the answer you were looking for, please do check it as the accepted answer and upvote it.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes it's a good answer, but not a great one. There are many instances in my data in which the date is exceeding above 31.

Answer (score 0):

Let's approach it in 3 steps as follows:

1. Get the date of month start `Month_Start` from `Year` and `Month`
2. Calculate the date offsets `DateOffset` relative to `Month_Start` from `WeekOfMonth` and `DayOfWeek`
3. Get the actual date `Date` from `Month_Start` and `DateOffset`

Here's the codes:

```
df['Month_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Month'] + '01', format="%Y%b%d")

import time
df['DateOffset'] = (df['WeekOfMonth'] - 1) * 7 + df['DayOfWeek'].map(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%A').tm_wday) - df['Month_Start'].dt.dayofweek

df['Date'] = df['Month_Start'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['DateOffset'], unit='D')
```

Output:

```
  Month  WeekOfMonth  DayOfWeek  Year Month_Start  DateOffset       Date
0   Dec            5  Wednesday  1995  1995-12-01          26 1995-12-27
1   Jan            3  Wednesday  2013  2013-01-01          15 2013-01-16
2   Oct            5     Friday  2018  2018-10-01          32 2018-11-02
3   Jun            2   Saturday  1980  1980-06-01           6 1980-06-07
4   Jan            5     Monday  1976  1976-01-01          25 1976-01-26
```

The `Date` column now contains the dates derived from the information from other columns.

You can remove the working interim columns, if you like, as follows:

```
df = df.drop(['Month_Start', 'DateOffset'], axis=1)
```